# assigning result of a function call, where the function has no return

Tags: python, tkinter, math

contexto: 'Haciendo una calculadora con interfaz en Python con las bibliotecas Tkinter y math'

Abajo de cada botón que le asigne a la interfaz me sale el error en la ventana PROBLEMS "assigning result of a function call, where the function has no return." independientemente de que en cada botón me de error, aun así funciona pero no entiendo el porque del error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *

ventana = Tk()
ventana.title ("Casio SuperPower 3000")
ventana.geometry("400x600")
ventana.resizable(False,False)
ventana.configure(background="gray42")


color_boton="gray99"
ancho_boton=10
alto_boton=3

operacion = ""
texto_pantalla = StringVar()
def clear():
    global operacion
    operacion = ""
    texto_pantalla.set("0")
def click(b):
    global operacion
    operacion += str(b)
    texto_pantalla.set(operacion)
def resultado():
    global operacion
    try:
        r = str(eval(operacion))
    except:
        r = "error404"
    texto_pantalla.set(r)

clear()

Boton0 = Button(ventana, text="0",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click(0)) .grid(row=1,column=0,pady=10)
Boton1 = Button(ventana, text="1",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click(1)) .grid(row=1,column=1,pady=10)
Boton2 = Button(ventana, text="2",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click(2)) .grid(row=1,column=2,pady=10)
Boton3 = Button(ventana, text="3",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click(3)) .grid(row=1,column=3,pady=10)

#segunda fila
Boton4 = Button(ventana, text="4",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click(4)) .grid(row=2,column=0,pady=10)
Boton5 = Button(ventana, text="5",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click(5)) .grid(row=2,column=1,pady=10)
Boton6 = Button(ventana, text="6",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click(6)) .grid(row=2,column=2,pady=10)
Boton7 = Button(ventana, text="7",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click(7)) .grid(row=2,column=3,pady=10)

#tercera fila
Boton8 = Button(ventana, text="8",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click(8)) .grid(row=3,column=0,pady=10)
Boton9 = Button(ventana, text="9",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click(9)) .grid(row=3,column=1,pady=10)
BotomPi= Button(ventana, text="π" ,bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click("pi")) .grid(row=3,column=2,pady=10)
BotonPunto = Button(ventana, text=".",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click(".")) .grid(row=3,column=3,pady=10)

#cuarta fila
BotonSuma = Button(ventana, text="+",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click("+")) .grid(row=4,column=0,pady=10)
BotonResta = Button(ventana, text="-",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click("-")) .grid(row=4,column=1,pady=10)
BotonMult = Button(ventana, text="*",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click("*")) .grid(row=4,column=2,pady=10)
BotonDiv = Button(ventana, text="/",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click("/")) .grid(row=4,column=3,pady=10)

#quinta fila
BotonRaiz = Button(ventana, text="√",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click(sqrt)) .grid(row=5,column=0,pady=10)
BotonClear = Button(ventana, text="C",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=clear) .grid(row=5,column=1,pady=10)
BotonEXP = Button(ventana, text="exp",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click(exp)) .grid(row=5,column=2,pady=10)
BotonIgual = Button(ventana, text="=",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=resultado) .grid(row=5,column=3,pady=10)

#sexta FILA
BotonParenIz = Button(ventana, text="(",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click("(")) .grid(row=6,column=0,pady=10)
BotonParenDer = Button(ventana, text=")",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click(")")) .grid(row=6,column=1,pady=10)
BotonPorc = Button(ventana, text="%",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click("%")) .grid(row=6,column=2,pady=10)
BotonLog = Button(ventana, text="Log",bg=color_boton,width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton,command=lambda:click("log")) .grid(row=6,column=3,pady=10)

pantalla = Entry(ventana, font=("arial", 20, "bold") ,width=22,borderwidth=10,background="deep sky blue", textvariable=texto_pantalla)
pantalla.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=4,padx=20,pady=20)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: No pongas a operación como string, ponlo como numero y si quieres al final lo conviertes a string

Answer (score 1):

Al crear un *botón* añades una llamada al método `.grid()` que no devuelve nada. Las variables donde crees que guardas el botón en realidad no están guardando nada.

La solución es usar dos pasos:

```py
Boton0 = Button(ventana, text="0",...)
Boton0.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=10)
```

Según la versión de python, se puede hacer en una sóla línea, aunque no quedaría muy legible:

```py
(Boton0 := Button(ventana, text="0",...)).grid(row=1,column=0,pady=10)
```

Comment: +1 por el ignorado y maltratado Walrus Operator.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono, disculpa lo molesto pero si no te complica me podrias explicar que estoy haciendo al ponerlo en otra linea? y porque se soluciona el error?

Comment: Lo que sucede es que `Button(...)` crea una instancia. Esa instancia tiene el método `grid()`, el cual no devuelve nada. Tú lo que estabas haciendo era concatenar la creación de la instancia con la invocación del método, y lo que devolviese eso (nada), es lo que estabas asignando a `Button0`.

Comment: Nuestro amigo Chema lo que está haciendo es crear primero la instancia de `Button`, guardarla en una variable, y luego invocar el método `grid()` a través de esa variable ya guardada.

Comment: @Vice Fíjate bien que estás asignando a las variables el resultado del método `Button(....).grid()`, que no devuelve nada (bueno, en realidad devuelve implícitamente `None`).  Al separar en dos líneas, primero guardas el botón en la variable y la siguiente línea invocas el método `.grid()`.